# What's this compiling error about mutex in C++11 with g++?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, mutex

What's this c++ compiling error? I've already compiled my code on another already configured machine so I guess I missed something in the environment to compile in C++11 (the code is compiled with --std=c++0x option). The error seems to be about new mutex functionality in C++11.

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/mutex:43:0,
                 from include/Ric_box_tele.h:4,
                 from src/Ric_box_tele.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional: In member function ‘void std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::__call(std::tuple<_Args ...>&&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes ...>, typename std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::__enable_if_void<_Res>::type) [with _Res = void, _Args = {}, int ..._Indexes = {0, 1, 2}, _Result = void, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (Ric_box_tele::*)(Socket, int)>, _Bound_args = {Ric_box_tele*, Socket, int}, typename std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::__enable_if_void<_Res>::type = int]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1378:24:   instantiated from ‘std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::result_type std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {}, _Result = void, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (Ric_box_tele::*)(Socket, int)>, _Bound_args = {Ric_box_tele*, Socket, int}, std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::result_type = void]’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:117:13:   instantiated from ‘void std::thread::_Impl<_Callable>::_M_run() [with _Callable = std::_Bind_result<void, std::_Mem_fn<void (Ric_box_tele::*)(Socket, int)>(Ric_box_tele*, Socket, int)>]’
src/Ric_box_tele.cpp:453:1:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1287:4: error: use of deleted function ‘Socket::Socket(const Socket&)’
include/Socket.h:43:5: error: declared here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:550:7: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘_Res std::_Mem_fn<_Res (_Class::*)(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_Class*, _ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = void, _Class = Ric_box_tele, _ArgTypes = {Socket, int}]’
```

Comment: `error: use of deleted function ‘Socket::Socket(const Socket&)’` which is caused by your `include/Socket.h`

Answer (score 5):

You have a method in `Ric_box_tele` that takes a `Socket` variable by value (signature appears to be `void method(Socket, int)` -- I do not know what the name of the function is, as you failed to include the line of code that generated your error).

`Socket` variables cannot be copied (their copy constructor is deleted).

The error is about what is on line 453 of your file `src/Ric_box_tele.cpp`, which you failed to include in your question.  On that line you are creating a `std::thread`, and probably passing it a socket, and maybe aforsaid method and a pointer to the object.

The Bind errors probably come from the ability for `std::thread` to take n-ary member function pointers and auto convert them into n+1-ary callables, with that being implemented in an implementation detail (probably `std::bind`, or equivalent internal machinery).  It just adds noise to the core error message.

In general, when decoding C++ library errors, you want to look at what line of your **own** code is mentioned, then you want to look at the innermost error.

The innermost error being `use of deleted function ‘Socket::Socket(const Socket&)’`, and the line of your own code being "line 453 of your file `src/Ric_box_tele.cpp`".  Everything else can be useful to see how the two connect to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think the mutex include is a red herring. Instead it looks like you're trying to copy a `Socket` at `src/Ric_box_tele.cpp:453` which is causing the error as `Socket`s are noncopyable.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to version of g++ (4.6 instead of 4.7). I guess the older one doesn't implement one C++11 feature I used so code following that line wasn't interpreted correctly.